# Facing issues running lerna commands in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo configured with `Lerna` and `yarn workspaces`.

At the same time, I have a Jenkins pipeline setup on AWS instance.

So all the `dev` and `prod` scripts are running without any issues on my local machine but when I try to run it in the Jenkins pipeline I get this error message.

```
> lerna bootstrap

lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info ci enabled
lerna info bootstrap root only
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/yarn'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101466:58
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseRcPaths (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101464:78)
    at Object.findRc (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101478:10)
    at getRcConfigForCwd (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:56957:74)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:92827:56
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VIshal-New-Setup/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
lerna ERR! yarn install --mutex network:42424 --non-interactive exited 1 in 'happydemy'
lerna ERR! yarn install --mutex network:42424 --non-interactive exited 1 in 'happydemy'
```

This is the build script running inside jenkins

```
#!/bin/bash


whoami
mkdir -p /root/.config/yarn
chmod 777 /root/.config/yarn

npm cache clean --force
npm i lerna --legacy-peer-deps
npm i yarn --legacy-peer-deps
npm run clean
npm run bootstrap
```

I am installing Lerna and yarn first, then I am running `lerna clean` then `lerna bootstrap`.

But when it runs `lerna bootstrap` it throws an error message.
If you see I have given the `777` permission to `root/.config/yarn` file but still I am getting this error.

Not able to understand if this issue is with yarn or lerna. I appreciate the help.